# I'm Stumped does anyone know what this could possibly say?

Tags: rebus

[image]

I can not figure out what this puzzle is. I have tried, I have researched and googled, and nothing is working. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Think it starts 'Long before it...'

Comment: Where does this puzzle come from?

Comment: I saw it on Facebook puzzle group I'm in and none of us can figure it out

Comment: Might start with "Before it's over...". Could contain "run after"

Comment: is there more to this image? I notice lines but I can't tell if they are part of the puzzle.

Comment: May contain "Be bold"? Or "boldy be"? "Belong"?

Comment: You imo have all missed the first word which is "FORT" '4 X it' the rest ought to fall into place. hint: simply look at names of forts or expressions which include "fort" (e.g., if it were a picture of a cow with a slash through it = Fort Knox) :)

Comment: So, don't keep us in suspense... what do you think the actual answer is?

Comment: sorry idk... but just trying to help and cannot, at least not now, follow my suggestion due to time.  But I expect the solution when I return to look again   lol.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 11):

**Okay I think I finally have it:**

> Its bee on words (***"It's beyond words"***)

Or it could also be said:

> Four its bee on words (***"For it's beyond words"***)

**Explanation**

The first part is as everyone assumed it was along the lines of:

> **"It"** is there 4 times so its either **"it's"** or **"For it's."** I think the only difficulty was how it related to "BEE."

And the second part was tricky:

> The word "Bee" is resting directly on a series of words that exemplify the different parts of speech, but don't make a sentence. We have **"Cow"** *(a noun)*, **"One"** *(which can be a number or a pronoun)*, **"Run"** *(which can be a verb or a noun)*, and **"As"** *(which can be an adverb, preposition, or a conjunction)*. These words were likely chosen because, while being only 4 words, they cover the essential parts of speech that compose a sentence. So this part of the puzzle is probably just "words." When "Bee on words" is spoken loosely, it sounds like "beyond words" --finishing the sentence.

**Other possible variants could be:**

> **"It's *over* beyond words"** (the "It"s are over "Bee" but it's not a common quote), **"It's *far* beyond words"** (the "It"s are far from the "Bee"), **"It's *simply* beyond words"** (there's a popular quote worded like this), or even **"It's *way* beyond words"** (the "it"s being far from the other words.) And any of these could have **"For"** at the beginning, but the wording I would go with is just ***"It's beyond words"*** because it's the most common phrase of all the possible variants.

After days of chewing on it, that's the best I've come up with. I hope someone can verify whether or not it's the right answer on your Facebook.

Comment: It like your answer.  The best I've been able to come up with is "It ain't over 'til it's over." (Explanation: It is **definitely** "it's over . . . **something,**" but it **ain't** "it's over 'til it's over."). And yeah, this is pretty weak.  I like yours much better.

Comment: Thanks, @Rob! I was thinking about the fact the word "Bee" was sitting directly on the other words, and playing with the possible wordings and then  it just clicked. I probably sounded like a psycho talking to myself randomly the past few days. Now I can sleep. =)

Comment: "Long bee on words" captures the senses of far or way

Answer (score 1):

I think it may also include the phrase -

> "reading between the lines" for its long beyond words

So maybe

> " reading between the lines for its long  beyond  words"??

Answer (score -1):

> Make a bee line for it. I think it could be the answer.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Please use the spoiler markup `>!`. Meanwhile, take the [tour.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Welcome! I think it would also help other users to understand your answer, if you explained why you think it might be correct ;-)